# Julia, how to plot behind previous plot (how to push a plot to the backgrown of another plot)

Tags: julia

I'm plottiong a sin and a cos function with the following code:

```
using GLMakie
x = range(0, 10, length=100)
figure, axis, lineplot = lines(x, sin)
lineplot2 = scatter!(x, cos, color = :red)
figure
```

`lineplot2` appears on top of `lineplot`, that is, the red dots appear on top of the blue line, effectively masking the blue line at some points.
How do I "push" the red dots so that they appear behind the blue line?

Answer (score 1):

found how to do it by using `translate!`

```
using GLMakie
x = range(0, 10, length=100)
figure, axis, lineplot = lines(x, sin)
lineplot2 = scatter!(x, cos, color = :red)
translate!(lineplot2, 0, 0, -1)
figure
```

Comment: The answer should at least be runnable, if not more verbose.